# Database Design For Social Network apps

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm going to build a social network app. Each user will have photos, videos, details, posts etc.

My question is when a new user registers, should I generate many new tables for that user or have one table for all users which may be contain billions of rows?

And which is best database for social network system: MySQL or CassandraDB?

Please help me!

Comment: Maybe you have a good idea, but I really recommend that you hire someone else to implement.

Comment: But i don't have much money right now! So i'm trying to do it by myself :)

Comment: Product recommendations are usually off-topic for this site.  That said, Cassandra has better sharding than MySQL.  I'd commend graph databases, such as Neo4j, for your investigation, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One table for all users.  Period.  End of discussion.  (This is a common question; the answer is always the same.)

When you get to a million rows, we can discuss some other issues and solve them before you embark on the road to a billion.

What is best for project X?  If it will have a billion rows, you *will* need a database expert to tweak whatever underlying system you are using.  Any system can do it.  But it won't be trivial.

Focus on getting to a million rows.  Reconsider *all* of your design decisions at that point.  Any decisions made today will *not* survive to 1 billion.

Would you like me to repeat myself all over again?

Comment: Thanks you so much :) But if i want to separate my database into many server, which database is best for doing that?

Comment: I can only speak for MySQL.  I have seen several "sharded" mysql installations doing things similar to what you plan.  It does, however, require programming on your part to implement the routing.  Hashing userid is a common sharding technique.  I could talk further, but it is a _big_ topic.

Comment: I recommend not embarking on sharding until you get closer to needing it.  By then, you will have fleshed out many of the other schema issues and can focus on sharding.